# Creating vCard file in .NET Compact Framework (C#)

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, vcf-vcard

Is there a built-in way to create vCard files in the .NET Compact Framework?
If not, what is a good library for this?

I have found this one which after some adaptations would seems to be able to do the job on the Compact Framework:
http://thoughtproject.com/Libraries/vCard/index.htm

But I'm not sure if there is not a build-in or more standard way to do it.

Regards,
Will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vCard is a universal protocol and you can use the library you've mentioned to generate vCards. There's not built-in api in ,net framework for vCard so far I know. You might need put some extra effort to port it to .netcf but it should not be a problem. As long as your code generates the vCard that conforms to the vCard protocol it should be good as such there's not standards defined on how to generate the vCards.

Answer (score 0):

Google-fu:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/NET_vCard_API.aspx

http://www.lumisoft.ee/lswww/download/downloads/Net/LumiSoft.Net.zip

I'm pretty sure there's nothing built in to .NET to handle vCard files.

Answer (score 0):

.NET CF is not a 100% complete subset of the .NET FCL but it is pretty darn close. To boot, the VCard format (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard) is fairly straightforward. I'm guessing that there's a 99% chance that the source from the vCard class library (built using .NET 2.0) will compile and behave just fine under .NET CF. The only thing you might need to watch out for is OS-specific calls like access to particular system folders, if the library needs any of that, which it shouldn't.