# Parsing a vCard (vcf) from its string value

Tags: c#, winforms, parsing, vcf-vcard

I managed to create a vCard using [LumiSoft](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2738722/1154184) and then get the string value of it

```
    LumiSoft.Net.Mime.vCard.vCard card = new vCard();
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
    card.ToStream(stream);
    stream.Position = 0;
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    return reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Here's an example of the returned string:

> BEGIN:VCARD VERSION:3.0 UID:f1a6090d-ee73-4368-8fe6-26302fb3e97a N:
>   LastName;FirstName;;; TEL;CELL:0099912123456 EMAIL:Rey@company.com END:VCARD

This is a standard string format on multiplaforms (mobile and desktop) to share contact information and I can't really change the format I send/receive the information for the vCard string. 
The send works successfully(on mobile, it parses this string successfully as a vcf card), the problem is parsing the received string on desktop (which is exactly the same as the sent string)...

What I tried is writing the received string to a stream then parsing it:

```
    LumiSoft.Net.Mime.vCard.vCard card = new vCard();
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.Write(cardString);
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    card.Parse(stream);
```

which failed. then to see what's happening, I tried writing the string I got to a local vcf file and opening it,

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.vcf", cardString);
```

and that failed too even though I crosschecked the 2 strings (sent and received) and they are 100% identical. (could be missing headers?)

Any help on how I can parse this string (mentioned above) to retrieve its info (name, email, photo...)? I noticed some SO posts mention using regex to achieve that but I was hoping to use a library instead, it doesn't have have to be using LumiSoft. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know LumiSoft, but your string

```
BEGIN:VCARD VERSION:3.0 UID:f1a6090d-ee73-4368-8fe6-26302fb3e97a N: LastName;FirstName;;; TEL;CELL:0099912123456 EMAIL:Rey@company.com END:VCARD
```

is not in a valid format.

It should be

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
UID:f1a6090d-ee73-4368-8fe6-26302fb3e97a
N:LastName;FirstName;;;
TEL;CELL:0099912123456 EMAIL:Rey@company.com
END:VCARD
```

Note the linebreaks instead of single spaces.

---

Maybe give [Thought.vCards](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Thought.vCards/) a try.

Comment: Formatted the string properly. Plus there was a hidden char being sent from our server at the beginning of the string which prevented the parsing. after I trimmed it out, all worked out. Thought.vCards looks pretty good thank you for your suggestions

Comment: Google Contacts manages `BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1` and Contacts (my Android Phone) `VERSION:3.0`

Answer (score 1):

EWsoftware.PDI - this is a good library for parsing and creating vCard files.
It is available as NuGet package. Serach for vCard or EWSoftware in the NuGet Manager in the Visual Studio.

This is a link to the description of the namespaces

[EWsoftware.PDI](http://ewsoftware.github.io/PDI/html/84784fc0-1a4e-4780-9a61-4abfda5592c1.htm)

In EWSoftware.PDI.Parser there is a class VCardParser which can parse a file and return a collection of vCard objects and in EWSoftware.PDI.Objects thre is the class vCard which also has WriteToStream method to put vCard objects in a file.